# InsertInto(tablename) always saving Dataframe in default database in Hive

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, hive, apache-spark-sql, hdp

Hi I have 2 table in my hive in which from first table i m selecting data creating dataframe and saving that dataframe into another table in orc format.I have created both the tables in same database.
when I am saving this dataframe into 2nd table I'm getting table not found in database  issue.and if i m not using any databasename then it always  creating and saving my df in hive default database.can someone please guide me why its not taking userdefined database and always taking as default database?below is code which I m using,and also i m using HDP.

```
    //creating hive session
    val hive = com.hortonworks.spark.sql.hive.llap.HiveWarehouseBuilder.session(sparksession).build()
    hive.setDatabase("dbname")
    var a= "SELECT 'all columns' from  dbname.tablename"
    val a1=hive.executeQuery(a)
    a1.write
    .format("com.hortonworks.spark.sql.hive.llap.HiveWarehouseConnector")
    .option("database", "dbname")
    .option("table", "table_name")
    .mode("Append")
    .insertInto("dbname.table_name")
```

instead of insertInto(dbname.table_name) if I'm using insertInto(table_name) then its is saving dataframe in default database. But if I'm giving dbname.tablename then its showing table not found in database.
I also tried same using dbSession using.

```
    val dbSession = HiveWarehouseSession.session(sparksession).build()
    dbSession.setDatabase("dbname")
```

Note: My second table(target table where I'm writing data) is a partitioned and bucketed table.

Comment: can you try to replace `insertInto` statement with `CREATE TABLE ...` SQL API statement?

Comment: 1. dbname - is created on moment insertInto... ?
2. when you use insertInto, you need created table before. try saveAsTable(...)

Comment: @mvasyliv Database and table already exists.2.Yes I have already created table.Tried saveAstable also but its taking lot of time so trying InsertInto.

Answer (score 0):

// 2. partitionBy(...)

```
{    a1.write
 .format("com.hortonworks.spark.sql.hive.llap.HiveWarehouseConnector")
 .option("database", "dbname")
 .option("table", "table_name")
 .mode("Append")
 .insertInto("dbname.table_name")
 // My second table(target table where I'm writing data) is a partitioned and bucketed table. add .partitionBy(<list cols>)
```

}